Pycharm: How to display project name instead of path

Pycharm: How to display project name instead of path
The screen shot above shows the project tool window. Under Project Files view, it display the entire path instead of just displaying the name of the project, is there a setting that allows me to change this? I only want to display the project name.

Possibly related or helpful: JetBrains/Intellij support link Show project name and/or full path in title bar

You can click on dropdown next to Project Files and change it to Project, that will show Project Name (and path as well).

Hope above helps your case.
